# Having troubles with pd.read_excel - UTF-8 doesn´t recognize special characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am facing a problem related to reading an Excel file using pandas which I have not been able to solve yet. The file

The file has several sheets, so I have written a function for each of them, what I aim is to automatize the splitting and saving for each of the sheets I am interested in.

The problem is that choosing encoding URT-8 I am not able to read the special characters we have in the Spanish dictionary such as:á, é, í, ó, ú, or ñ.  I had a similar issue reading a CSV, which I solved using encoding Latin-1 and engine python. However, it seems I cannot use either this encoding or the engine since it is Excel file (I might be wrong, but I haven't been able to run the chunk because it throws me an error).

Here is the code ( I'm just writing one of the functions since they are pretty much the same, the only thing that changes are the directories):

```
# I am joining the path and the path and the name of the excel I have previously written 
path_final = os.path.join(path, excel)


# Reading the excel choosing the sheet I want:
df_employees = pd.read_excel(path_final, sheetname='General (employees&interns)', encoding='UTF-8')

# Path to the directory I want to save the CSV in.   
employees_path = General/03 HR Analytics/01. Dashboard/'+ year +'/'+ month +'/Processed/Employees/'

# We save it, with the name and format 
df_employees.to_csv(employees_path +"HR_Data_Template_Data_" + business_list[position]+"_Employees.csv" , sep=';', encoding='UTF-8')
```

And this is what excel looks like before and after they´ve gone through the functions. These names have been made up for the example:

---

```
# Before (original):
 Carreño Julian
 Natalia García 
 Gutiérrez Gutiérrez Pedro

# after:
 CarreÃ±o Julian
 Natlaia GarcÃ­a 
 GutiÃ©rrez GutiÃ©rrez Pedro
```

---

Do you know what might be that cause because UTF-8 is not working reading excels? Do you guys know an alternative way of doing it?

If you have encountered the same problem, please give me a hint!

Comment: So the mojibake happens in *a CSV*? How exactly did you open that CSV and checked its contents? With Excel? Excel notoriously sucks at reading anything but plain ASCII CSVs.

Comment: @deceze Hey, so the mojibake happens whenever I read the excel in Python. UTF-8 or Latin-1 encoding isn't working with the panda's read_excel function.   Nevertheless, I had this same problem reading a CSV with pd.read_csv in the past but I fixed it using those encoders. So, I assume there might be one way of doing it by reading excel files.    And I am reading the excel because I want the functions to split the excel in three different csvs instead of doing in my self, but I encountered this issiue.

Comment: At which point are you checking the output and how? From your question it sounds like you pipe an Excel file into Python, which produces a CSV, and then you open the CSV in Excel and you see garbage there. Is that what's happening? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @deceze You are right, I check it after saving the CSV. But, If I checked the data frame right when I read the excel it happens as well, I can see the strange characters there. So, that made me think the issue takes part at the beginning and not while saving the output.

Comment: Well, that's the question. Narrow it down enough to be clear and reproducible for us here.

Comment: @deceze I just happen to solve the issue. Checking thoroughly I noticed the issue was happening when saving the CSV, so I was wrong before. I used this encoder ' utf-8-sig' instead of 'utf-8'. I saw on Youtube that on windows many editors assume the default ANSI encoding instead of UTF-8 if there is no byte order mark (BOM) character at the start of the file. So using that encoder, we add de BOM.  <<https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WgVz0vxdJrE>>

Comment: So as I said before: Excel simply notoriously sucks reading CSV files! If you looked at your CSV using any other tool, it'd probably be fine.